# Audio format when using captureAudio()

Tags: codenameone

With my application, the user can capture audio, export it and play it back on a web page.

I am able to capture audio and play it back on device but I have to export the file. I do it by transforming it to byte[] and then encode it in Base64.
So I export it by sending the resulting String and in my PHP, I decode it. The problem is that it's imposible to play it back, a file is created on the server but unplayable.

In what format is the audio file made with captureAudio() ? Should I put an extension in the file name like .mp4 or something else ? (I already test .mp4 and .m4a)
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there was a corruption in the file along the way. You can easily verify that with a filesize+checksum (checksum is generated by adding up all the bytes in the file).

The file type generated by capture differs by platform e.g. on iOS you would probably get an AAC file where in Android you'd probably get an mp3 file (not mp4 which is a video format).

You can also use the low level audio capture API which provides details about the specific codec used. This API is available in `MediaManager`.